# Download file thru website from another server

Tags: php, server, request, web, backend

I have a website on one server and lots of storage on another server.

When user access the page I show file names fetched from server with lots of storage.

Is it possible to somehow proxy a download so that when user want to get a file it will be send thru a server with website without downloading it to 
 the site with webpage?

What is best solution to this problem?

Comment: Just provide the user with a direct link on the storage server for the file which he can access via http. Now if your storage server can only be accessed through VPN or FTP or some other way the user doesn't have access to, that's a different thing.

Comment: If you simply don't want to send your users to the server where the files are hosted,  I can give you a HTML, PHP or jQuery solution.

Comment: Thanks for replay. for security reasons I would rather not give access or address of storage server. I would like to pass the file thru the web server even that I know it adds another point of failure in whole system. So on web server I mount a folder to storage server via FTP and then allow user to download a file from web server which resides on storage server. correct? or is there more optimal approach?

Comment: @ChukaOkoye what's the solution?

Comment: Do you want pure php or JavaScript?

Comment: I use both in my scripts. Lets say PHP.

Comment: @otakon could you find the solution? I have the same requirement.